# How to use meta tag to declare http Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: html, cross-domain, meta, cross-domain-policy

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is typically declared as an HTTP header to enable a browser to fetch content from remote domains. Is it possible for this to be declared via the HTML `<meta>` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Only real HTTP headers can be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

In .html files

In .php files
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Client Side**

```
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*" />
```

**Server Side**

Remember that you must include the corresponding header.

PHP Example:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

You MUST have the HTML tag AND the Server Header.